# How do I recover my WhatsApp messages when the phone is lost?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I lost my phone with some  unopened  important document in my WhatsApp account, and I can't get the  same  number because  I'm currently  out  of  the country where I can replace my line. So, how  do I recover  my  messages in such case?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible without using same number because Whatsapp runs only on mobile.

Whatsapp doesn't have any email id or login functionality.

**Update : 8th Jan 2016.**

Now Whatsapp added backup functionality using Google Drive. So you can also take your chat backup if you lost your mobile.

[image]

<sub>Screenshot - Click to enlarge</sub>

Comment: Even if you get a new SIM card with the same number, I'm not sure it's possible without the original phone or the backups.

Comment: Actually it does. Your ID is your phone number and your password is the one sent to you. However, cloud backup isn't a feature of Whatsapp.

Comment: On latest app on PlayStore. you just need to install/update your app and then you have google drive based back up option in it.